# Form php not working

Tags: php, forms

I have gone searched the net and tried many ways of creating and validating a form which sends info to an email but I can't get my head around it. This is what I have done and it seems to work (have not been able to test if it sends), but every time I submit it comes up with "all fields required error" even with all boxes filled/empty. I looked on this site through similar questions and tried to fix it by them but no luck.

What am I missing? 
Should I use the php on another page?
Once the error is fixed, will it send and keep the information submitted by the user?

In case it helps - I'm using foundation 5 for the site. Beginner at PHP.

```
<?php
$action=$_REQUEST['action'];
if ($action=="") 
{
?>  
<form action="" method="post">
<div class="row">
<div class="large-12 columns">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
<label>Name
<input name"name" type="text" placeholder="Your name"/>
</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="large-12 columns">
<label>Email
<input name"email" type="text" placeholder="Your email" />
</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="large-12 columns">
<label>Your Message
<textarea name="message" type="text" placeholder="Comment here"/></textarea>
</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="large-12 columns">
<input id="submit"  type="submit" value="Send Message">
</div>
</div>
</form>
<?php
} 
else                
{
$name=$_REQUEST['name'];
$email=$_REQUEST['email'];
$message=$_REQUEST['message'];
if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($message==""))
{
echo "All fields required! Please fill <a href=\"\">in the form</a> again.";
}
else{        
$from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email";
$subject="Hire";
mail("myemail", $subject, $message, $from);
// back to homepage - will add send confirm when fixed. header( "Location: ");
}
}  
?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You are missing `=` on `name"name"` and `name"email"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `=` to assign value for your `name` attribute:

```
<input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name"/>
<!-------  ^ here
```

and:

```
<input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Your email" />
<!-------- ^ and here
```

Comment: Don't I feel stupid for not noticing this, it works and receiving email. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You are giving input attribute `name` for name and email like this :

```
 <input name"name" type="text" placeholder="Your name"/> 
<input name"email" type="text" placeholder="Your email" />
```

Change it to

```
 <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name"/> 
<input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Your email" />
```

Answer (score 0):

check this ..Add`=` to email and name

```
 <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name"/>
    </label>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
    <label>Email
    <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Your email" />
    </label>
```